# python - Can't use gmsh after installing via pip and conda

Tags: python, ubuntu-20.04, gmsh

I installed gmsh but I can not use it in spyder.
I used the following:

```
pip install gmsh
conda install -c conda-forge gmsh
```

but when I run the following code:

```
import gmsh
gmsh.initialize()
```

I get the following error:

```
No module named 'gmsh'
```

I'm using ubuntu 20.04 and spyder 3.3.6

Comment: Are you sure you've selected the correct interpreter for spyder? If you run `python -m pip freeze | grep gmsh`, do you see that package installed? Can you verify that `python -m pip -V` shows the same interpreter path as what you have selected in your IDE?

Comment: If I simply `python -m pip install gmsh` and then run `python -c 'import gmsh'` I don't get any errors

Comment: how do you run the code?

Answer (score 6):

The `gmsh` package in `conda-forge` don't provide the Python API. Please install gmsh using `pip install gmsh`. If you still prefer to use conda, you can download the `python-gmsh` package from the `conda-forge` channel using `conda install -c conda-forge gmsh python-gmsh`. Here you will find the Python API you're looking for.