# Importing gmsh gives OSError

Tags: python, gmsh

I'm trying to import the gmsh python package but getting the following error. I installed gmsh using `mamba install python-gmsh` (which I got from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70947216/python-cant-use-gmsh-after-installing-via-pip-and-conda)) inside Ubuntu but I'm importing the module within Pycharm on Windows using WSL.

```
File "/home/mai/mambaforge/envs/myenv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/gmsh.py", line 86, in <module>
    lib = CDLL(libpath)
  File "/home/mai/mambaforge/envs/myenv/lib/python3.9/ctypes/__init__.py", line 374, in __init__
    self._handle = _dlopen(self._name, mode)
OSError: libGL.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

I've installed gmsh previously using mamba and it worked but this time it's giving issues.

Edit:  I found out it was because I was missing OpenGL. It comes preinstalled on Windows/Linux but not with WSL it seems.

Comment: What version of gmsh is this?

Comment: @starball 4.11.0

Comment: Please always [edit] clarifications into your question post instead of hiding them in the comments. Comments are for _soliciting_ clarifications- not for providing them.

Comment: This part of your question doesn't make sense to me: "installed [] inside Ubuntu but I'm importing the module within Pycharm on Windows". Are you using a shared filesystem between Ubuntu and Windows? Or are you using WSL?

Comment: @RolandSmith I'm using WSL. I have pycharm pro so just set  the interpreter to use WSL

Comment: Do you have `gmsh` installed in WSL? Does it work?

Comment: @RolandSmith Yes, that's where I used the mamba install command. I created an environment and installed gmsh inside it but I get the above error when I try importing it.

Comment: What I was trying to ask is, does `gmsh` *itself* work? Can you start it, does the GUI appear?

Comment: @RolandSmith I found out it was because I was missing OpenGL. It comes preinstalled on Windows/Linux but not with WSL it seems.